# Unable to find files in Documents from cmd

Tags: cmd, document

I am using Windows 10 and when I save a document I see the Documents folder it is being saved to on the left of the screen in the list under 'thisPC'. The bottom of that list has the C: drive. From Powershell, Bash or command prompt when I try to cd or locate the file I just saved I am told that it cannot find such a file. Why is my home directory the C: and not include the other files I mainly work with? I appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: When I open `cmd` the prompt defaults to `C:\Users\PaulT` ... so, what do you mean by the home directory being `C:` ? If I do `dir Documents` from my prompt shows the files. You may have to provide more info. There are ways to change the prompt's default, but not sure what you expect?

Comment: Are you sure that you are checking in the correct location? The `Documents` link you're clicking on in Explorer is most probably the 'Documents Library', which usually shows items in multiple locations, not just the 'Documents Directory' within the users own profile.

Answer (score 1):

Command prompt works with files and folders.

Explorer works with virtual files or folders. Explorer is for users to easily find their stuff.

In Command prompt there is no such thing as `This PC` or anything under it. These are virtual things.

```
dir "%userprofile%\documents"
```

will list the files in your Documents folder if it is in the default location.